# The List joinedTeams using C# throwing exception

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have used below code basically to fetch all the teams which I joined from Microsoft Teams using Microsoft Graph API SDK in C# but its throwing below exception.

```
var joinedTeams = await graphClient.Me.JoinedTeams
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

**Exception:**

The collection type 'Microsoft.Graph.IUserJoinedTeamsCollectionPage' is abstract, an interface, or is read only, and could not be instantiated and populated. The unsupported member type is located on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Graph.Team]'. Path: $.value | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 97.

Below is the reference of Microsoft documentation which I used,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Is this a known issue in Microsoft Graph API? Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Graph.Beta with version 0.25.0-preview . The most latest one I am using.

Comment: Please check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62530532/how-to-fix-differences-on-call-microsoft-graph-calendar-between-net-core-and-n
Do you try to run the code on .NET Framework or on .NET Core?

Comment: I have tried to run this code on .NET Framework.

Comment: Also, the above question is irrelevant to what I posted :)

Comment: To me, it looks very relevant: notice that the author started getting a very similar exception after switching from .NET Core to .NET Framework. And you happen to run on .NET Framework as well.
BTW, I can help to debug, but please post the minimum solution that builds and reproduces the issue.

Comment: Okay. Could you please try to use Graph API to fetch the list of teams you joined using the link of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp . I am facing the issue while calling this API only. I am able to fetch the users information using graph API.

Comment: I'm still willing to help but don't have a working Teams organization that I can use to debug. Can you share some temporary account info and the ClientID for your Teams app?

Comment: Could you please provide more information regarding the issue.

Comment: @PravinDurgam, It is working as expected. can you please share your complete code (method).